# Defining a manual Split algorithm for File Input

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I'm new to Spark and the Hadoop ecosystem and already fell in love with it. 
Right now, I'm trying to port an existing Java application over to Spark.

This Java application is structured the following way:

1. Read file(s) one by one with a `BufferedReader` with a custom Parser Class that does some heavy computing on the input data. The input files are of 1 to maximum 2.5 GB size each.
2. Store data in memory (in a `HashMap<String, TreeMap<DateTime, List<DataObjectInterface>>>`)
3. Write out the in-memory-datastore as JSON. These JSON files are smaller of size.

I wrote a Scala application that does process my files by one worker but that is obviously not the most performance benefit I can get out of Spark.

Now to my problem with porting this over to Spark:
The input files are line-based. I usually have one message per line. However, some messages depend on preceding lines to form an actual valid message in the Parser. For example it could happen that I get data in the following order in an input file:

1. {timestamp}#***0x033***#{data_bytes} \n
2. {timestamp}#***0x034***#{data_bytes} \n
3. {timestamp}#***0x035***#{data_bytes} \n
4. {timestamp}#0x0FE#{data_bytes}\n
5. {timestamp}#***0x036***#{data_bytes} \n

To form an actual message that out of the "composition message" 0x036, the parser also needs the lines from message 0x033, 0x034 and 0x035. Other messages could also get in between these set of needed messages. The most messages can be parsed by reading a single line though.

Now finally my question:
**How to get Spark to split my file correctly for my purposes? The files can not be Split "randomly"; they must be split in a way that makes sure that all my messages can be parsed and the Parser will not wait for input that he will never get. This means that each composition message (messages that depend on preceding lines) need to be in one split.**

I guess there are several ways to achieve a correct output but I'll throw some ideas that I had into this post as well:

- Define a manual Split algorithm for the file input? This will check that the last few lines of a split do not contain the start of a "big" message [0x033, 0x034, 0x035].
- Split the file however spark wants but also add a fixed number of lines (lets say 50, that will do the job for sure) from the last split to the next split. Multiple data will be handled by the Parser class correctly and would not introduce any issues.

The second way might be easier, however I have no clue how to implement this in Spark. Can someone point me into the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your comment on my blogpost on http://blog.ae.be/ingesting-data-spark-using-custom-hadoop-fileinputformat/ and decided to give my input here.

First of all, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. Help me out here: your file contains lines containing the 0x033, 0x034, 0x035 and 0x036 so Spark will process them separately? While actually these lines need to be processed together?

If this is the case, you shouldn't interpret this as a "corrupt split". As you can read in the blogpost, Spark splits files into records that it can process separately. By default it does this by splitting records on newlines. In your case however, your "record" is actually spread over multiple lines. So yes, you can use a custom fileinputformat. I'm not sure this will be the easiest solution however.

You can try to solve this using a custom fileinputformat that does the following: instead of giving line by line like the default fileinputformat does, you parse the file and keep track of encountered records (0x033, 0x034 etc). In the meanwhile you may filter out records like 0x0FE (not sure if you want to use them elsewhere). The result of this will be that Spark gets all these physical records as one logical record.

On the other hand, it might be easier to read the file line by line and map the records using a functional key (e.g. [object 33, 0x033], [object 33, 0x034], ...). This way you can combine these lines using the key you chose.

There are certainly other options. Whichever you choose depends on your use case.

Comment: Why I originally started this question: I thought that Spark will possibly split up my file at a wrong line. 
By that I mean, that Spark could decide to make a new split just when the last line is the start of a "composition message", thus contains [0x033] in my example. It would break my Java-Parsing-Code due to that I think that each Split will (possibly) be processed by a different worker and thus have no access to previous lines.
This is why I thought I need to "preprocess" it with a custom input format to make sure that all these depending-on-other-lines messages can be parsed correctly

Comment: Your second suggestion might be another way to handle my problem. Thanks for bringing this up.

I have some more questions on that: 
- Each of my file contains up to 50.000.000 lines. Would this introduce a problem with mapping the lines into the format you proposed? 
- How can I process each of these Key/Value-Lists ([object 33, 0x033], [object 33, 0x034], ...) afterwards?  
- What happens when one key, for example "object 33" as you named it, got like 70% of the values in total? Will this be split up for further processing somehow?

Comment: For your first comment: Spark can only _decide_ to make a new split somewhere else when you program it that way. I.e. create a fileinputformat that defines how you want the file to be splitted. You are correct when you say that splitted records can be processed by different workers. I think a fileinputformat might be a valid solution for your problem!

Comment: For your second comment: the idea is that you choose the key "object 33" so that it is unique for each logical record. This way lines for the same logical record will be _reduced_ by the same worker. If that is possible that is, otherwise this option isn't the way to go. When a reducer needs to process too many keys (e.g. 70% of all values like you say) I think the reduce step will be very slow or may even run out of memory. I'm not sure about this. A situation like this should be avoided at all times by choosing a good (more selective) key.

Comment: I went on and built up a map task that groups my lines to their producer as you proposed. It is working fine for smaller files but fails on bigger files. Because the topic of that problem is slightly different from this, I created a new topic with additional information. Do you think my approach is the correct one to choose? Or would you rather go for a custom input format? See: [Huge memory consumption in Map Task in Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569635/huge-memory-consumption-in-map-task-in-spark)